# Mixed-effects models with lasso penalty and ridge penalty in R

Tags: multilevel-analysis, lasso, random-effects-model, ridge-regression

I am using the PISA 2015 data and trying to run a mixed-effects ridge and lasso regression model Schools will be included as a random effect, and student-level (e.g. motivation, socioeconomic status, epistemic beliefs) and school-level (e.g. percentage of students from disadvantaged families, student-teacher ratio, professional development availability) predictors will be included as fixed effects. The response/outcome variable is scientific literacy scores of students.

I am using R to run my analyses. I have tried using *lmmlasso::lmmlasso* to specify the mixed-effects lasso model (it is the only package I found that does such an analysis), but found that there is a problem/error with this package. "This error comes from the package *penalized* which lmmlasso is built on, which has apparently been classified on CRAN as ORPHANED" (see https://github.com/yonicd/lmmen/issues/3#issuecomment-478418540). I have searched for a package that runs mixed-effects ridge models, but to no avail...

My question is - Does anyone know of an alternative package I can use to run mixed-effects models with lasso penalty and ridge penalty in R?

Comment: Question...why do you want to use lasso? I ask because the multilevel/mixed efffects model has a lasso flavor to it with random intercepts and slopes, which shrink unreliable groups toward the mean. So you could potentially include random slopes for your student-level variables at the school level.